# facebook error code 102 with sdk 3.6

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

```
Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)" UserInfo=xxxx {error_code=102, action_id=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx, error_message=Could not generate preview text, app_id=xxxxx}
```

This error appears when I press the post button in my app and the device switches to the facebook app to post my OG action. As soon as the facebook app opens and my og action text is visable this error gets logged and my device switches back to my app. Does anybody know what it means?

Answer (score 3):

This may not be your problem, but I had this problem when I was trying to `presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:actionType:previewPropertyName:handler:` with an action type that had not yet been approved by Facebook. When I was using the app with a user that is not an administrator or developer of the app, I would see this error.

Per the note at the top of the Action Type page (accessible from developer.facebook.com > apps > Your App (on left hand side) > Edit App > Open Graph > Types > Your Action Type),

> **Unsubmitted**
>
> This Action Type must be submitted for review in order for
>   it to be available to all users. This Action Type is available to
>   admins and developers of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem because I was in sandbox mode for my fb app. So I use my own developer account to login in and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check Following

1. **FacebookDisplayName** is set properly and correct in plist URL Scheme
2. **fbxxxxxxxxxxx** is added in the plist
3. **FacebookAppID** is set correctly in plist file
4. in **Status & Review** section Make sure you have "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" make as YES (By default it's No)