# Facebook SDK - Open Graph - Share Dialog post button greyed out - error code 102

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following the tutorial for `Publishing using the Share Dialog` on the `Custom Stories in iOS` section.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph

When I want it too, it switches to the Facebook App, the Graph Object is presented to the user (image, title etc) for a few seconds and then disappears and `Post` button greys out. If I tap the Post button before it greys out, I get an error message logged:

```
Error publishing story: Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)"    
UserInfo=0x16d48640 {error_code=102, app_id=1435110413425124, 
error_message=An error occurred during publishing.}
```

FYI, the standard share dialogue `presentShareDialogWithLink:handler:` is working fine and letting me post - it's just when I present one with a Graph Object attached to it.

I would post sample code, but it'm using the same code that's in the tutorial above. Besides, I'm pretty sure this is to do with settings in the App Dashboard, not the code I'm writing.

Per this question on Stack Overflow [Facebook SDK - iOS - Fail to share URL (Error 102)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541510/facebook-sdk-ios-fail-to-share-url-error-102), I've confirmed that:

- My App's Settings are set correctly in App Dashboard (including iPhone Store ID and Bundle ID)
- By info.plist file is configured correctly.

This question [facebook error code 102 with sdk 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990874/facebook-error-code-102-with-sdk-3-6) suggested using a real Facebook user who was an administrator of the app. I tried that, but the problem still occurred for me.

I also tried it with the App published, and with it unpublished and there was no difference.

**I'm wondering if anyone else has any ideas for things I haven't checked yet?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm a numpty.

Despite the fact I said I'd checked the settings were correct in `App Dashboard`, I had misspelt the `Namepsace`.

Answer (score 0):

If your Facebook app status is "development and unavailable to the public" will caused same result.

You may want to change it to public under "App Review" on the Facebook app menu. Or you need to login Facebook as role "Administrators", "Developers" or "Testers"